# asp.net Session timeout issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

got a problem with my asp.net mvc project timing out after only a couple of minutes.  It's especially annoying because I've got quite a complex upload and import procedure which falls over when i get logged out.  I currently use asp.net membership provider for authentication.

I've tried a few things that I've seen on this site and others but to no avail.  Here is what I have so far in the web config:

```
<location path="Admin/Upload">
   <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1200"/>
   </system.web>    
</location>

<system.web>       
<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="20" cookieless="false" />

<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="20" />
</authentication>

<add name="ConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=SERVERNAME;Database=DBNAME;User Id=USER;Password=PASSWORD;timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

I was sure it was only a minute before being timed out before I added the sessionstate timeout, then it was upped to 2 mins, but can't be 100%.

I thought about using this:

```
<lifetime leaseTime="15M"/>
```

...but not 100% sure how to implement it - anyone had any success with it, or know something else I could try?

Thanks

EDIT:  I'm on a cloud hosting solution, but only have a control panel - no access to IIS

UPDATE:  I've now tried adding lifetime leasetime and it's not made any difference:

```
  <system.runtime.remoting>
    <application>
      <lifetime leaseTime="20M"  />
    </application>
  </system.runtime.remoting>
</configuration>
```

UPDATE 2:
Ok, I've edited the title and the web config values to reflect my latest effort, but I'm still struggling.  I spoke to the hosting company who set the connection timeout to 20 minutes.  However, it the session ends after 10 mins.  Is there anything else I can try?

I'm getting there, but I would like 20 minutes!

Comment: Why are you using the `<location>` element to manage authorization in an ASP.NET MVC application instead of decorating your controllers/actions with the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: Hi Darin.  I have actually used the [Authorize] attribute - this was just something I added yesterday when I was looking for a solution

Comment: When does it timeout ? During the upload ? While idling ?
I was thinking of an Application Pool issue (worker process recycled...)

Comment: Well, both actually.  If you login and just leave it for 3 mins +, then click on a link that you need to be authorized for, it redirects to the login screen.  During the upload, it goes through a few actions that require authorization, so redirects to the login screen before the upload/import is finished.  I've read about the worker process recycle issue - can anything be done to prevent this on a shared server using a shared application pool?

Comment: The hosting company didn't think it was the application pool recycling, although I'm running out of ideas for what else it could be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I got a solution to this, but it wasn't what I was expecting.

It turned out I was using the aspnet Membership Provider wrongly.  I was using like a previous membership system I worked on and logging in then setting the UserId as a session variable and using that throughout the site.  I then discovered that is the incorrect way to use it, and changed it to a combination of `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` and `Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey`.

It no longer times out and all is well.  Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The lifetime leasetime tag goes in the application tag.

```
<application>
   <lifetime leasetime = "15M"/>
```

I've never actually used it but if it is like other timeouts idk if you will need the M at the end. That is pure speculation though. You should also be able to set it to "0" so that its lifetime is "forever"

As for the session timeout that looks like it should be set for 100 minutes. However, it should be inside of your `<configuration>` tags

**EDIT**
Completely unrelated to the question kind of. But i like how your runtime execution timeout is "over 9000"

Comment: Ha - I just copied and pasted that code block in - never really questioned the timeout amount!  Regarding the sessionState tage - it is in the Configuration tag.  But then pretty much the whole of the web config is.  I didn't see the sense in pasting the whole lot - I just put snippets in.

Comment: Well, assuming the code that you copied it from didn't have a specific reason as to why it had to be 9001, i'm guessing it's because they are a DragonBall Z fan lol. Were you able to get this up and working or are there still problems occurring?

Comment: Yeah problem still occurring unfortunately.  Lifetime leasetime didn't make any difference